# Laravel eloquent busqueda en campos de modelos relacionados

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Necesito hacer una busqueda de proyectos cuando la variable $buscar en el modelo proyectos coincida con el campo nombre o en el campo nombre del modelo clientes

**MODELO PROYECTO**

```
   public function clientes()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Clientes');
}
```

**MODELO CLIENTES**

```
   public function proyectos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Proyectos');

}
```

*MI CODIGO*

```
  $buscar = "archelier";

    $proyectos =Proyectos::select()
    ->where('nombre', 'LIKE', '%'.$buscar.'%')
    ->orWhere('Clientes', function($q){
    $q->where('nombre', '%'.$buscar.'%');
    })->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No especificas si ya tienes las respectivas relaciones en tus modelos, ya que no es nada extenso, las voy a incluir mas abajo. Si no lo tienes hecho y deseas comprender como funciona, puedes leer al respecto en [eloquent-relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships).

Modelo **Cliente**:
*Relación uno a muchos. Suponiendo que un cliente puede tener mas de un proyecto, pero un proyecto solo puede pertenecer a un cliente.*

```
    public function proyectos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Proyectos');
    }
```

Modelo **Proyecto**:
*Relacion inversa.*

```
public function cliente()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Cliente');
}
```

**Consulta con Eloquent**:

```
$buscar = "fran islas";

$proyectos = Proyecto::whereHas('cliente', function ($query) use ($buscar) {
        $query->where('nombre', 'like', '%'.$buscar.'%');
    })->orWhere('nombre','like', '%'.$buscar.'%')->get();
```

Con whereHas aplicamos la condición correspondiente a la tabla relacionada, en este caso sería la tabla "clientes"(modelo cliente). Luego con orWhere aplicamos la condición en la tabla "proyectos". Todo esto lo puedes leer en la documentación oficial (el mismo link que dejé mas arriba).

Espero que te sirva, Saludos!